# Display a list of content inside an other content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to know if it's possible in drupal-7 do make a list of a specific content type into an other content.

Not sure if there is such an option in Drupal. (I jsut started to use it)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do but maybe  you are looking for the entity reference module: https://drupal.org/project/entityreference

Edit: views module is what you need: https://drupal.org/project/views

Comment: Yep, that almost do it but, for example a nodes has a title field, I'd like to know if I can make a list with the node title and the link into it... If no, I can make it with php but I don't know how to put php in a page content lol

Comment: http://www.webdellarte.com/espace-client/exiles/models This is my test page. I have contents title here, but I need to retrieve fields off those two pages

Comment: Awesome :D This is perfect (bit confuse but) so nice !

Comment: Good. A display block should be fine. Once done a new block will appear in the blocks list and you will be able to place it in the region of your choice.

Comment: Is there any problems that you have not accepted the answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the views module is the ideal choice for making customised lists of content. Its is also easier to layout these lists if you use the panels module https://drupal.org/project/panels